# Jumping animation on Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I have a problem that I don't know how to make animation logic, and maybe how to unite clips between them
[Animation tree where, each transition on jump is like Isjumping = true, then IsFalling = true etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAvsq.png)
[And if needed, my jump script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANA90.png)

```
 RaycastHit hit;
        bool isFalling = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.Normalize(_controller.velocity)), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, 1);
        _animator.SetBool(_isJumpingHash, !_isGrounded);


        if (isFalling)
        {
            if (hit.distance >= _raycastDistance && transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.Normalize(_controller.velocity)).y <= 0)
            {
                _animator.SetBool(_isFallingHash, true);
            }
            else
            {
                _animator.SetBool(_isLandingHash, true);
            }
        }
```

That's current Hanlder jump animation but it doesn't work.

my script is based on CharacterController, how do i do?

I tried different methods from internet, but my animation wasn't work

Answer (score 0):

Although this question of yours is broad and does not deal with a specific problem, that's why I flagged it. But I want to remind you of key points that will definitely be useful to you. As you know, with the development of animator, this method of creating a parameter for each state makes the work more difficult and complicated. So you need a way of parametrization that keeps the dynamics and works for you in different parts. Now look at the code below.

```cs
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
private bool _isGrounded;
void Update()
{
    _isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.up, out var hit, 1, groundLayer.value);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) 
    {
        // jump is Trigger cuz is playing once when pressing key
        _animator.SetTrigger(_isJumpingHash);
    }

    // set Y velocity as float to animator to make it dynamic
    _animator.SetFloat("yVelocity", _controller.velocity.y); 
    // The presence of isGrounded in the animator itself is also useful and prevents possible bugs along with other conditions.
    _animator.SetBool("isGrounded", _isGrounded);
}
```

Above I tried to pass `yVelocity` directly to the animator instead of taking a Boolean for `isFalling`. Because it makes you have more freedom in the animator. For example, if the falling speed increases, we can switch to another animation, or anywhere else the `isFalling` animation will work automatically. Now it is enough to determine the states that can be entered in the animator.

- In **Jumping** and **Move** State (or even **Idle**), set the falling condition as below (`yVelocity` less than `-.1`).
- For **Jump** (or any once action behavior) just create a **Trigger** and set it when jump key pressed.
- For Landing set `isGrounded` to animator and set same condition for it.
- Other than the condition of exiting from **Landing** to Move state, other conditions disable `hasExitTime`.

[image: Animator]

[image: Condition]

[image: Landing]

Comment: thanks for idea,i really appreciate, but my controler.velocity.y doesn't change when im jumping

Comment: so it's only jumping and landing animation trigered
here my transitions :
Movement(it's a blend tree) -> falling (yVelocity less -0.1)
Movement -> Jumping (isJumping triggered)
Jumping -> Landing (isGrounded true)
Jumping -> Falling (yVelocity less -0.1)
Landing -> Movement (isGrounded true)
Falling -> Landing (isGrounded true)

i think that's it

Comment: @ultramax4528 If you use a controller, you must code gravity and `yVelocity` changes in update. If you use `rigidbody`, get rigidbody velocity. It makes no difference. It is important that the animator has the falling speed.